# Maple solve system of equation showing "RootOf"

Tags: solver, maple

I'm trying to solve the following system:

```
gx:=2*x*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*y
gy:=2*y*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*x
sys:={gx=0,gy=0}:
solve(sys,{x,y})
```

It then displays the following output:

```
{x = 0, y = 0}, {x = RootOf(2*_Z^2-ln(2)), y = RootOf(2*_Z^2-ln(2))}, {x = -RootOf(2*_Z^2-ln(2)-I*Pi), y = RootOf(2*_Z^2-ln(2)-I*Pi)}
```

The first "root" (0,0) is correct, however how do i remove that root of and whatever Z that is? Is it possible to get the correct answer out of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great scenario for the function [`allvalues`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=allvalues).
From the help page:

> compute all possible values of expressions involving RootOfs

```
gx:=2*x*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*y;
gy:=2*y*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*x;
sys:={gx=0,gy=0}:
sol := solve(sys,{x,y}):

seq(allvalues(sol[i]), i= 1..numelems([sol])):
print~([%])[];
```

[image: Output of allvalues version 1]

Notice, however, that you are not getting all solutions this way. There are infinitely many solutions to the problem; to get all solutions, use the optional argument `allsolutions = true` in the solve command:

```
sol2 := solve(sys,{x,y},allsolutions = true):
seq(allvalues(sol2[i]), i= 1..numelems([sol2])):
print~([%])[];
```

[image: Output of allvalues version 1]

If you run this, you will see a new variable `_Z1` that has a trailing tilde (`~`) - this tilde means there are assumptions on the variable. To see these assumptions use

```
about(_Z1);
```

> ```
> Originally _Z1, renamed _Z1~:
>   is assumed to be: integer
> ```

This means that the above solutions work for any integer `_Z1`. Those are all your solutions and written in the expected way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fsolve` to final numerical solutions,

```
restart;
gx:=2*x*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*y;
gy:=2*y*exp(x^2+y^2)-4*x;
sys:={gx=0,gy=0}:
fsolve(sys,{x,y})
```

> {x = .5887050113, y = .5887050113}

```
sys:={gx=0.,gy=0.}:
solve(sys,{x,y})
```

> {x = 0., y = 0.}, {x = .5887050112, y = .5887050112}, {x = -.5887050112, y = -.5887050112}, {x = -.9887236333-.7943556085*I, y = .9887236333+.7943556085*I}, {x = .9887236333+.7943556085*I, y = -.9887236333-.7943556085*I}

Comment: That's not correct tho, as I need multiple solutions displayed.

Comment: @Dapper See the Edit